# Display slash command only to user with a specific role / permission in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this discord.py command:
(It basically allows mods to send any message 'as the bot' to maybe troll other users)

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="say", description="Says something")
@app_commands.describe(channel="The channel you want to send the message to", message="The message you want to send")
async def say(interaction, channel: discord.TextChannel, message: str):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel.id)
    await channel.send(str(message))
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Message sent! {channel.mention}", ephemeral=True)
```

Now I want to make it so that the slash command only gets shown to users with `Administrator` permissions. How can I implement that? I'm thankful for any help! Have a nice day!

Comment: Your slash command can be configured like that, however the only way is to modify the server settings as follows (not using discord.py): `Server Settings` > `Integrations` > `YourBot` > `YourCommand` > `"Add roles or Members"`

Comment: That worked, thank you! If my bot was public tho, every server would have to set it up separately, right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, however, you can add a condition, preventing users without certain permissions from executing the command

Comment: @Astral It's important to know that this only stops them from *executing* the command instead of *showing* it. However, you can probably make a tutorial on how to do that on bot joining a server.